# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "'messages' is a required property" when testing the API with Postman

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

How do I successfully get a completion back from the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model? This is what I've tried with Postman:

**post**

```json
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

**body**

```json
{
    "model":"gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "max_tokens":512,
    "top_p":1,
    "temperature":0.5,
    "frequency_penalty":0,
    "presence_penalty":0, 
    "prompt":"给我讲一个笑话吧"
}
```

**headers**

```json
Authorization `Bearer apikey`
```

I get the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "'messages' is a required property",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference between the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3 API) and the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) is the following:

- Completions API: required parameters are `model` and `prompt` (see the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create))
- Chat Completions API: required parameters are `model` and `messages` (see the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create))

So, when using the Chat Completions API (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API):

1. The `prompt` parameter is not even a valid parameter because it's replaced by the `messages` parameter.
2. The `messages` parameter is required.

Try the following:

**Request**

```
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

**Body**

```
{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}],
    "max_tokens": 512,
    "top_p": 1,
    "temperature": 0.5,
    "frequency_penalty": 0,
    "presence_penalty": 0
}
```

**Authorization**

```
Bearer sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Headers**

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message you received basically informs you, that you haven't provided a required property `messages` in your request body (you are using `prompt` instead).

If you want to see a working example of a chat-completion request, please see the documentation for the example API calls:

- Directly in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/devrel/workspace/openai/request/13183464-3b16e75d-8ddd-4758-aaea-4097c9f93f54)
- [openai](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction)

Your working example could look something like this:

```
{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "给我讲一个笑话吧"
        }
    ],
    "temperature": 1,
    "max_tokens": 512,
    "top_p": 1,
    "temperature": 0.5,
    "frequency_penalty": 0,
    "presence_penalty": 0 
}
```